# Take hot wire from pot lights for fan

Tags: electrical

I’ve got pot lights hooked up to a switch (typical daisy chain install nothing fancy). Is it possible to install a fan off of one of the pot lights, but make the fan always on since it’s on a remote? I have no attic access and there’s a giant header I’d rather not have to drill through if I can grab power from a pot light instead. Any suggestions help.

Comment: The hots on those light are really switched hot and are control by the switch(in most cases).  We would really need to know how the lights are wired up.  Turn off the breaker and just pull the switch from the wall.  Do not remove/disconnect any wires.  We just need some pictures showing how the wires are connected to the switch.

Comment: **If** it's possible at all, it's very likely only possible from one, specific light (where power comes in from the breaker panel and goes out to the switch and comes back to the lights) but it could be that power comes from the breaker panel to the switch, and **only** switched hot is available at **all** the lights. The previously requested pictures would inform that (but not tell which light, until you look at the wiring in all of them.)

Comment: If the wiring doesn’t work out, maybe put smart bulbs in and control them remotely. The whole circuit will be energized all the time and the fan will have power.

Comment: I was thinking the same as @AloysiusDefenestrate.  If this is a standard switched circuit, smart bulbs are probably your best option.  What you do may depend on whether you have a neutral at the switch.